# Way to allow for duplicate many-to-many entries in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have the following Django model:

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    icons = models.ManyToManyField(Icon)
```

When I write the following code:

```
post = Post()
icons = []
icon_id = form.cleaned_data['icon_1']
if (icon_id):
    i = Icon.objects.get(id=icon_id)
    icons.append(i)

icon_id = form.cleaned_data['icon_2']
if (icon_id):
    i = Icon.objects.get(id=icon_id)
    icons.append(i)

post.icons = icons
post.save()
```

It works fine for the most part, creating a Post object and the two Icon objects.

However, if the icon_id is, say, 1 in both cases, it only creates ONE entry in the database, not two.

So it seems like it checks for duplicates and removes them.

How do I make this work so I allow duplicates? (I want two of the SAME icon associated with a post.)

Thanks!

Comment: i don't understand.  why are you attaching two icons with the same ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define the model yourself, to have such non-unique many-to-many relations

```
class PostIcon(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(Icon)
```

and than add them one by one

```
for icon in icons:
    PostIcon(post=post, icon=icon).save()
```

or pass that model as `through` argument of `ManyToManyField` e.g.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    icons = models.ManyToManyField(Icon, through=PostIcon)
```

or alternatively you can have a count associated with `PostIcon` instead of having multiple rows, if that serves the use-case e.g. you may want a badge to be displayed 10 times

```
class PostIcon(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(Icon)
    count =  models.IntegerField()
```