# How to allow duplicate values in a ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I have implemented a ManyToMany relationship that allows duplicate items as in [Way to allow for duplicate many-to-many entries in Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260716/way-to-allow-for-duplicate-many-to-many-entries-in-python-django). I also have a form, that uses a ModelMultipleChoiceField for this relationship, in order to validate the data that come from an ajax request but after the form is_valid() call, any duplicate items in the ModelMultipleChoiceField are eliminated. Is there any way to keep the duplicate items (I am not interested in the presentation of the form, as I don't use it in a webpage) or do I have to manually go over the request.POST data after the form validation?

Answer (score 0):

`ModelMultipleChoiceField` uses a queryset inside it so every item appears only once (as long as you don't use `join`'s in database queries, but it's unrealted to this question anyway). You can try using simple `MultipleChoiceField` and construct `choices` manually duplicating necessary values.

Comment: I considered using MultipleChoiceField, but I don't know which values are going to be used more than once. Even if I knew those values beforehand, there would have to be more than 5000 choices which doesn't sound like a good idea fetching them from the database each time a request is made.

Comment: But you have posted data when you are constructing a form, so you can filter all objects and construct a select with only needed data. Kinda stupid, but it should work :)