# Assigning Tag to object in Django ORM many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I have three tables. `Tag`, `QueryStringTag`, and `QueryString`. `QueryStringTag` a third table that is created to connect `Tag` and `QueryString` and allow one `Tag` to be associated with many `QueryString`'s and vice versa. It contains two foreign keys. One pointed at `Tag` and one pointed at `QueryString`.

The flow goes like this. A `QueryString` object is created and saved in the database. After this, 4 `Tags` are created. I want to associate those takes with the particular `QueryString` object.

I have failed at all attempts so far. The docs are not providing much help and I have tried just about everything I can think of.

***Here are my models...***

```
class QueryString(BaseObject): 

    server_id = models.IntegerField()
    schema = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    query = models.CharField(max_length=60000) 
    variables = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_created')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='queries_last_edited')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    touched_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    config = models.TextField(blank=True)
    runs_started = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    runs_completed_duration = models.IntegerField(default=0) # total number of seconds spent running this query to completion
    formats = "pretty_html html json prettyjson csv excel tableau".split()

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class QueryStringTab(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='querystringtag')
    querystring = models.ForeignKey(QueryString, related_name='querystringtag')
```

***Here is my view...***    
*(Keep in mind that `query` is a unique `QueryString` object that I am trying to associate with the four tags below)*

```
tags = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

for tag in tags:
    newtag = Tag(name=tag)
    newtag.save()
    query.querystringtab.tag(newtag.pk)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest searching about here on StackOverflow. I found two probably relevant answers searching "python django many to many":

For example:
[Way to allow for duplicate many-to-many entries in Python/Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260716/way-to-allow-for-duplicate-many-to-many-entries-in-python-django)